# Литература по Visual Fox Pro

Tags: база-данных, книги

Кто знает хорошую литературу по этой СУБД, пожалуйста, в студию. Буду очень признателен!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может чего-нибудь из этого вам [подойдёт](http://free-book.at.ua/news/1-0-19).